# python3_5 in PYTHON_TARGETS not working in Gentoo?

Tags: linux, python, gentoo, portage

I've added `PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_5 python3_4"` to my `/etc/portage/make.conf`.

When trying to install any program that supports python targets the following happens:

```
sudo emerge --ask dev-python/google-api-python-client

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/httplib2-0.9.1  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) (-pypy3)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/pyasn1-modules-0.0.5-r1  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) (-pypy3)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/linecache2-1.0.0  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) (-pypy3) (-python3_5)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/simplejson-3.8.1  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) (-pypy3) (-python3_5)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/uritemplate-0.6  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) (-pypy3) (-python3_5)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/traceback2-1.4.0  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) (-pypy3) (-python3_5)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/rsa-3.2.3-r1  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) (-python3_5)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/oauth2client-2.0.1  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) (-python3_5)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/google-api-python-client-1.5.0  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy)" 

Would you like to merge these packages? [Yes/No]
```

As you can see python3_5 is disabled for some reason and I don't know how to fix it. I also tried to add `python_targets_python3_5` to my USE flags, but it has no result.

```
$ eselect python list
Available Python interpreters:
  [1]   python2.7
  [2]   python3.4
  [3]   python3.5 *
```

What I should do to get python3.5 flag support enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to solve this issue.

You need to edit `/usr/portage/profiles/base/use.stable.mask` and comment out following lines:

```
python_targets_python3_5
python_single_target_python3_5
```

And here we go:

```
sudo emerge --ask dev-python/google-api-python-client

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] dev-python/six-1.10.0  PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_5*" 
[ebuild   R    ] dev-python/setuptools-20.6.7  PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_5*" 
[ebuild   R    ] dev-python/certifi-2015.11.20  PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_5*" 
[ebuild     U ~] dev-python/pyasn1-0.1.9 [0.1.8] PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_5%*" 
[ebuild  N    ~] dev-python/httplib2-0.9.2-r1  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 -pypy -pypy3" 
[ebuild   R    ] dev-python/pbr-1.10.0  PYTHON_TARGETS="python3_5*" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/simplejson-3.8.1  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 (-pypy) (-pypy3)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/uritemplate-0.6  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 (-pypy) (-pypy3)" 
[ebuild  N    ~] dev-python/pyasn1-modules-0.0.8  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 -pypy -pypy3" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/linecache2-1.0.0  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 (-pypy) (-pypy3)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/traceback2-1.4.0  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 (-pypy) (-pypy3)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/rsa-3.2.3-r1  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 (-pypy)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/oauth2client-2.0.1  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 python3_5 (-pypy)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/google-api-python-client-1.5.0  USE="{-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy)"
```

**UPDATE**: This changes will be overwritten by system updates, so you need to update `/etc/portage/profile/use.stable.mask` with following lines:

```
-python_targets_python3_5
-python_single_target_python3_5
```

Thanks to [jansegre](https://www.reddit.com/r/Gentoo/comments/5ajn24/python3_5_in_python_targets_not_working_in_gentoo/d9hb6ss/) from Reddit.